# Is there a way to change the colors of the menu item icons and text?

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles, android-menu, android-vectordrawable

I have menu items on a navigation drawer like this:

```
        ...
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_item_language"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_language"
            android:title="@string/language" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_item_theme"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_theme"
            android:title="@string/theme" />
    </group>
    <group
        android:id="@+id/nav_group_intents"
        android:checkableBehavior="none">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_item_share"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_share"
            android:title="@string/share" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_item_rate_app"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_rate"
            android:title="@string/rate_app" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_item_contact_us"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_contact_us"
            android:title="@string/contact_us" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

[image]

I want the texts and the icons to be the darkest black (#000000) on dark theme and the lightest white (#FFFFFF) on light theme but now they are always some shade of gray.

I have tried placing this as an attribute in the menu item:

```
<item
    app:iconTint="@android:color/black"
    android:id="@+id/nav_item_language"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_language"
    android:title="@string/language" />
```

And adding these items on the style:

```
<style name="AppThemeLight" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        ...
        <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/black</item>
    </style>
```

For the dark theme I try the same but `@android:color/white` instead and no matter what I do I can't change them from their default gray colors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your layout xml file you have NavigationView.To change the color of icon and text just add these codes,

```
app:itemIconTint="#00xxxx"
app:itemTextColor="#00xxxx"
```

Answer (score 0):

For the menu text color, In your themes file change the `itemTextAppearance`

```xml
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar.Bridge" >
  ...
  <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/menuItemColor</item>
</style>
```

In your styles create the `menuItemColor` style

```xml
<style name="menuItemColor" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.IconMenu.Item">
  <item name="android:textColor">?android:attr/textColorPrimary</item>
</style>
```